# How to prove 1-norm radial function is kernel?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, radial-basis

How should I prove that is a valid kernel:

$K(x,y)=exp(-\alpha||x-y||_1) $

As I understand, there are three ways to prove that

1. prove $K(x,y)=<\phi(x) ,\phi(y) >$
2. prove $\sum_{j,k=1}^n a_j\,a_k\,K(x,y) \geq 0 \  $
3. use Bochner's theroem

I don't know which way should I use.

**Update**

Actually , I have already tried to prove $K(x,y)=<\phi(x) ,\phi(y) >$, but I got stuck.

Here is my progress: 
[image]

As you can see, $n_i $ is not always equal to $m_i$ , for all $ i=1,2,...p$,

That means, I failed to prove  $K(x,y)=<\phi(x) ,\phi(y) >$.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.